# No message appears when losing a privilege

Tags: feature-request, reputation, notifications, privileges, notification-bar

In SO I reached 2000 in reputation. A message appears on top of the screen telling me that I can edit questions and answers.

I placed a bounty for 50 rep. In that moment, of-course I lost my editing privileges as I lost 50 rep. leaving me with 1950 in total.

I think it is better that a message appears also in this case to notify me somehow that I lost this privilege.

Comment: It's a fairly rare edge case - but does come up from time to time. Most of the time you're going to remain above the privilege threshold.

Comment: Yes, but like I was informed of earning the privilege - the same must happen if I lose one.

Comment: `Congratulations! You lost the privilege: Comment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to let users know that they have new abilities they may not understand so they aren't confused by new options, such as "close".

There's no particular need to alert a user who has lost an ability - when they try to use one they are familiar with they will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better alternative would be to show you or a moderator what your privileges actually are (sort of like the flag statistics link). There are already plenty of messages notifying you of various things. I'd hate for that status bar to get any more cluttered.